# How to know selected menu item in Win32 API

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, win32gui

In window API, I have a popup menu which contains 3 items "Line","Circle" and "Exit" respectively.

My program is to let the user select a shape to draw then takes the points, parameters (i.e. start and end points of the line,...). This is part of the code i've written so far.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    HMENU hMenu;
    POINT point;
    HDC hdc;
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    static int x1, y1,x2,y2,count = 0;
    switch (msg) {

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        count++;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            x1 = LOWORD(lParam);
            y1 = HIWORD(lParam);
        }
        else
        {
            x2 = LOWORD(lParam);
            y2 = HIWORD(lParam);

            // I think the problem goes here, it never execute else part 
            //even if global_ID ==2, Am I missing something?

            if (global_ID == 1)//Line
            {DirectMethod(hdc, x1, y1, x2, y2, RGB(0, 0, 0));}
            else if (global_ID == 2)//Circle
            {Ellipse(hdc, x1, y1, x2, y2);}
            count = 0;
        }
    case WM_COMMAND:

        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDM_FILE_LINE:
            global_ID = 1;
            break;
        case IDM_FILE_CIRCLE:
            global_ID = 2;//Global Variable
            break;

        case IDM_FILE_QUIT:

            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
        }

        break;

    case WM_RBUTTONUP:

        point.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        point.y = HIWORD(lParam);

        hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
        ClientToScreen(hwnd, &point);

        AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_LINE, L"&line");
        AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_CIRCLE, L"&Circle");
        AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
        AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_QUIT, L"&Quit");

        TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
        DestroyMenu(hMenu);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

What I wanna do is, based on selected menu item (Line, Circle,...) I execute specific piece of code which depends also on getting mouse clicks from user (WM_LBUTTONDOWN).

**For example:**
If the user selected "Line", I should take two points to draw that line.

Comment: What is your actual question? Your code is already detecting which menu item is selected, that is reported by the `WM_COMMAND` message. So, your problem is just gathering the user inputs? For instance, you could have your `WM_COMMAND` handler set a flag indicating the number the coordinates needed, and then have your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP` handler save coordinates until that number is reached. What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The problem is when a menu item is selected I change "global_ID" value to know which menu item is selected, but inside "WM_LBUTTONDOWN" it "always" execute the if statement and never executes else part, and I've debugged that code and "global_ID" is set to "2". What I mean it suppose to execute "else" part but it always execute "if" part

Comment: You should have stated those details in your question. What you describe should not be possible given that `global_ID` is not local to `WndProc()`, so any value that `WM_COMMAND` assigns would be carried through to subsequent `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. However, there are logic holes in your code: 1) you are counting mouse clicks even when you shouldn't be. When you do set `global_ID`, you are not resetting `count` to 0; 2) `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` should not be doing anything at all when `global_ID` is not 1 or 2; 3) you are not resetting `global_ID` after calling `DirectMethod()`/`Ellipse()`...

Comment: ... and 4) your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is missing a required `break` statement, so every mouse down message will fall through to the `WM_COMMAND` code.

Comment: You're missing a `break;` at the end of your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You saved my day, thank u so much, idk how I did miss those naive mistakes. It works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are logic holes in your code:

1. you are counting mouse clicks even when you shouldn't be. When your `WM_COMMAND` handler sets `global_ID`, you are not also resetting `count` to 0, so a subsequent click may end up skipping the assignment of `x1`/`y1` since `count` may already be `> 0`.
2. your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler should not be doing anything at all when `global_ID` is not 1 or 2.
3. you are not resetting `global_ID` after calling `DirectMethod()`/`Ellipse()`, so `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` will just keep counting clicks endlessly and performing its drawings on every other click.
4. your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is missing a required `break` statement, so every `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message will fall through to the `WM_COMMAND` code.

Try this instead:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int x1, y1, x2, y2, count = 0, global_ID = 0;

    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            switch (global_ID)
            {
                case 1: //Line
                case 2: //Circle
                {
                    ++count;
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        x1 = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                        y1 = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x2 = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                        y2 = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

                        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

                        if (global_ID == 1) {
                            DirectMethod(hdc, x1, y1, x2, y2, RGB(0, 0, 0));
                        }
                        else {
                            Ellipse(hdc, x1, y1, x2, y2);
                        }

                        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

                        global_ID = 0;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDM_FILE_LINE:
                    global_ID = 1;
                    count = 0;
                    break;

                case IDM_FILE_CIRCLE:
                    global_ID = 2;
                    count = 0;
                    break;

                case IDM_FILE_QUIT:
                    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    break;
            }

            break;
        }

        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        {
            POINT point;
            point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            ClientToScreen(hwnd, &point);

            HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();        
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_LINE, L"&line");
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_CIRCLE, L"&Circle");
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_QUIT, L"&Quit");
            TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
            DestroyMenu(hMenu);

            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```